# Update an empty cell in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, replace

I was wondering if there is any way to select an empty cell in a MySQL table and update it's value.

This is the structure of the table :

```
col 1 | col 2 | col 3  
      | a     | aaaa  
      | a     | aaaa  
      | a     | aaaa  
      | a     | aaaa
```

I would like to have something like

```
col 1 | col 2 | col 3  
bbbb  | a     | aaaa  
bbbb  | a     | aaaa  
bbbb  | a     | aaaa  
bbbb  | a     | aaaa
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `update yourtable set row1='bbbb'`?

Comment: you may just update the table where col is empty.

Comment: have you tried select 'bbbb',row2,row3 from yourtable

Answer (score 2):

You should simply update table with sql

```
UPDATE table SET row1 = 'bbbb' WHERE row1 = ''
```

Comment: 26744 rows affected. (Query took 0.3000 sec)

Answer (score 1):

An [update](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php) statement will do it:

```
UPDATE table t SET t.row1 = 'bbbbb' WHERE t.row1 = '';
```

There's no need to select anything to make an insert in this case, you just need to know which column you wish to update, the value you wish to update to and the WHERE's condition, that is, the previous col's value.